# Using Java Regex in order to find a subtring withing another substring

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have got a program that takes user input in a form of logical expression (for example: (p=>(r||q)) ) and it divides the string in to substrings which are defined by brackets. I am using pattern and matcher.
So, for example user inputs:
**((p||q)=>r)**.
I want to get 2 substrings which are:
**p||q**
and
**(p||q)=>r.**
However I am only getting this:
**(p||q**

Here is the code that I am using

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter formula: ");
 String formula = scanner.next();
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formula);
         while(matcher.find())
         {
          String s = matcher.group(1);

          System.out.println(s);
          }
```

So I need a way that the program finds all the substrings in that string.

Comment: Regular expressions are poorly suited to this task.  I suggest you do the parsing manually or make use of a parsing library.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with regular expressions.

Because the usage of brackets is a sign that what you want to do goes beyond the capabilities of regular expressions. Regular expressions describe a Chomsky-3 grammar which can't have bracket structures. Bracket structures are available in Chomsky-2 grammars. So you have to define a corresponding grammar with parsing rules. A good library that might help you achieving what you want is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, regular expressions do not handle nested brackets well at all.  However, parsing them manually is extraordinarily simple if you have a stack.  Here is some sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    findSubExpressions("((p||q)=>r)");
}

private static void findSubExpressions(String input) {
    Deque<Integer> startingBrackets = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(') {
            startingBrackets.push(i);
        } else if (c == ')') {
            int correspondingStart = startingBrackets.pop();
            logSubExpression(input.substring(correspondingStart+1, i));
        }
    }
}

private static void logSubExpression(String subExpression) {
    System.out.println(subExpression);
}
```